# Don't move sticky posts to the first page

Tags: sticky-post

After I sticky post, it automatically moves post to the first page and I'd like it to stay at it's recent place. Don't want it to move. How can I do this?
I just need sticky post option (i've got an option to sort posts in slider by sticky posts) but without any of its functionalities
I'm using ToroPlay 3.1 theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Don't change the core feature. If you really wanna do this then you need to find another solution for creating custom Category and add some styling for that category.

2: WordPress will add category classes on each post if your theme doesn't disabled it. Then you need to write CSS for that classes and it's gonna be resolved.

3: If you wanna use the theme sticky post styles. Then in your theme folder style.css, There have a .sticky classes out there and you need to change it or add your category css.

Thanks.